# How to handle a blog where each post is fundamentally different in structure but has the same overall appearance?

Tags: html, css, angular, format, blogs

I am looking to make a blog about 3D modelling using Blender. I would like each post to be unique in its core, but similar in style to other posts and the overall website. The framework I plan on using is Angular.

My main concern though is that I would like to be able to store the actual contents in a backend as a plain text file which can be fetched by the frontend (somehow?). I think it would be cool to have several hyperrefs to sources (i.e., videos, other blogs, articles, etc.), but I would also want to stylise the headers, perhaps certain keywords in the text using boldfaces, perhaps other fonts, etc. I don't think there exists any kind of easy to use file formats to both write the text as well as store this stylistic elements.

So my question really is, how would you go about storing a large chunk of text that is supposed to have arbitrary style elements, but allow for extraction of the core text as if non of the style elements were there? I want to be lazy and just write my h1, p, etc, figure out the layout using css as usual, but I don't see an easy way to retrieve the core text from that. The text would be stored explicitly in the frontend as pure HTML (or jsx I guess).

What does the industry do for these kinds of situations? I will leave a link to a page on a site called fandom: https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Dominator_GTX, there are numerous posts like this page, though each such post has a different structure regarding headers, images, etc.

Thank you.

P.s., I am not sure if this is the right place for questions like these.

Comment: The question is to broad / vague, IMO. Basically, this is what HTML was invented for. For simpler needs there is markdown. It depends which level of abstraction you want. -- "The industry" stores data in specifically designed data bases, with all the needed information. That data in the database can be transformed to specific "views", like "nicely formatted view" and "raw data view" and others. E.g. there are [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) libraries.

Comment: If I knew how to make the question specific, I wouldn't need to ask it in the first place :)
Indeed, a colleague of mine proposed markdown as well, it is straightforward and easy to use for simple tasks. Do you have any CMS in mind that works well for structured text?

Comment: No, I don't have experience with such CMS.